# AngularFire2 How to CreateUser ( name, surname, email, password )

Tags: database, angular, registration, angularfire2

I know how to create user with Email and Password, but how can i create him with also name and surname?
This is my code form email and password

```
registerUser(formData) {
    if(formData.valid) {
        this.af.auth.createUser({
            email: formData.value.email,
            password: formData.value.password,
            }).then((success) => {
                this.routing.navigateByUrl('/login');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

I cannot just write

```
registerUser(formData) {
    if(formData.valid) {
        this.af.auth.createUser({
            email: formData.value.email,
            password: formData.value.password,
            name: formData.value.name, // this is error :(
            surname: formData.value.surname, // this is error :(
            }).then((success) => {
                this.routing.navigateByUrl('/login');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'this.af.auth.createUser' only accepts an email and password. Also, you cannot have a custom property (name or surname) on Firebase's built in user profile.

The only available properties are:

- displayName
- email
- photoURL
- providerId
- uid

So you could definitely store it in 'displayName' if you wanted, otherwise you're going to have to use the Firebase Realtime Database to store additional user data. I believe to set 'displayName' you'll have to have the person signed in.

To use displayName you can do the following (once you have the signed in user):

```
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Name here"
}).then(() => {
  // Update successful
}
```

To use the Firebase Realtime Database:

```
registerUser(formData) {
    if(formData.valid) {
        this.af.auth.createUser({
            // Create user
            email: formData.value.email,
            password: formData.value.password
        }).then((user) => {
            // User created now create the database user
            return this.af.database.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).update({
                name: formData.value.name,
                surname: formData.value.surname
            });
        }).then(() => {
            // Success
            this.routing.navigateByUrl('/login');
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Error
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

(Not had chance to test the above code).